# The best way to get nearest street view by using getPanoramaByLocation with radius larger than 50 meters

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I know that getPanoramaByLocation with radius less than 50 meters will return the nearest street view pano.   However, for some locations, there is not always a street view.  So what I am doing is like this:

```
function insider_function(locations) { 
    var place = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[local_idx].lat,locations[local_idx].lng);
    sv.getPanoramaByLocation(place, 50, function(data, status) { 
    if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) { 
         insider_function_2(locations[local_idx], data); 
    } else { 
        sv.getPanoramaByLocation(place, 100, function(data, status) { 
        if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) { 
            insider_function_2(locations[local_idx], data); 
        } else { 
            alert('Internal error: ' + status + locations[local_idx]); 
        } 
    }
}
```

If radius 50 didn't return any result, I invoke radius 100.  But still I am getting alert for ZERO_RESULT for some address.  If I pass a very larger number, say 9999, I may get a very far street view for most other location with a closed street view.

So what is the best way to get the nearest street view pano with radius larger than 50.

I am not sure how google map do this.
For example, if I use "2300 Geng Rd, Palo Alto, CA" which coordinates are 37.4513333,-122.1214268.  getPanoramaByLocation with radius 100 will return ZERO result but there is street view in :
https://www.google.com/maps/place/2300+Geng+Rd,+Palo+Alto,+CA+94303/@37.4513333,-122.1214268

Answer (score 2):

A Google engineer in this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8971) explains this problem. Here are two options gained from that thread.

1. Use a radius of 1000 (1K) which works "most" of the time in getting the closest pano. (I have found this does work fairly well.)
2. Run two or more searches. Start the search with a large radius and work your way down, rather than starting small and working up. When a pano location is found with the large radius, use the distance between you search point and the resulting pano found as the radius value for your next search. According to the engineer's comments, you will "probably" only need to run two search requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it with radius 200, it will display a street view, you can check out this `jsfiddle link`: http://jsfiddle.net/8ujnbh62/ 
Because there is no street view data around your address with radius 50. But if you provide a larger radius, it will show a street view.

From the Google Map link you provided (https://www.google.com/maps/place/2300+Geng+Rd,+Palo+Alto,+CA+94303/@37.4513333,-122.1214268) it does not give you the street view of "2300 Geng Rd, Palo, Alto, CA", instead it gives you the street view of the E Bayshore road, which is about 200 radius away from "2300 Geng Rd".

In your situation, you might just make another function with a larger radius, if the Google Map does not return you any street view data.

Comment: So I have to invoke sv.getPanoramaByLocation multiple times for a given location to get a closed street view? That will delay the website to finish loading.

Comment: Or you can use a larger radius instead.